# VBA: Filter, copy values from external workbook, and past into active workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a simple solution to this problem.

the code below is my attempt, is the filtering portion for the source workbook correct in its approach?

Also, I want to insure the sourceworkbook is left was it was upon filtering and copying

Many thanks for any ideas!

```
Sub CopyFilteredValuesToActiveWorkbook()

    Dim sourceValues As Range, targetValues As Range

    Set sourceValues = Workbooks("\\Linkstation\rrm\X_DO_NOT_TOUCH_CC\MasterLogFile\Masterlogfile.xlsx").Worksheets("LogData").Columns("A:Z") 


    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$3").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Opera" 


    Set targetValues = Workbooks("\\Linkstation\rrm\Campaign Creator\RAW DATA GENERATOR OPERA.xlsm").Worksheets("MLF").Columns("A:Z")             

    sourceValues.Copy Destination:=targetValues

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this - defining the workbooks / sheets as variables makes it a lot easier to manage everything. I assumed you'd want the macro to open the other workbook for you - if not, the code can be altered easily.

```
Sub CopyFilteredValuesToActiveWorkbook()

Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim rngSource As Range, rngDest As Range

Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("\\Linkstation\rrm\X_DO_NOT_TOUCH_CC\MasterLogFile\Masterlogfile.xlsx", , True) 'Readonly = True
Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("LogData")
wsSource.Range("$A$1:$H$3").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Opera"
Set rngSource = wsSource.Range("A:Z")

Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook
Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("MLF")
Set rngDest = wsDest.Range("A:Z")

rngDest.Value = rngSource.Value 'Copies values over only, if you need formatting etc we'll need to use something else

wbSource.Close (False) 'Close without saving changes

End Sub
```

Comment: Many Thanks, I am having a few teething problems.. When I run the macro, the window opens saying: "file is already open, reopening will mean existing file is disgarded", which is obvious because the active workbook would have to be open anyhow!   Also the sourceworkbook remains open?

Comment: I edited it slightly a few minutes ago - now it uses "thisworkbook" which is where the macro is being run from (I assume this is where you want the data to end up). Try it now and see if the source book closes - I guess it didn't get to the close line before.

Comment: Brilliant stuff. Works perfectly. I have checked the tickbox.. has it added to your reputation?

Comment: is there a way to do this simply WITHOUT having to open the source workbook?  I have seen something called the ADO functionality, but it seems pretty complex. I am hoping this might aid processing speed very much?

Comment: I've not used ADO / OLEDB to connect to closed XLSX workbooks so don't know of any performance implications - may be worth submitting that as a new question.